# AgGrid v30 adding column from sidebar

Tags: ag-grid

I am trying to add columns from the sidebar in agGrid v30. When i click on checkbox the column is displayed in the grid for few seconds and goes away after that.
Can anyone help me out?

I am getting no console errors. Everything else in the grid is working as expected.